# How to use mmenu without breaking core Overlay

Tags: javascript, modal-dialogs

How can I use [mmenu jquery library](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl) without breaking core Overlay. Overlay works, but when I do a page refresh (F5) the overlay is blank. When I prevent the mmenu library from loading it works again.

I load the library in hook_preprocess_html in my custom zen theme:

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'zen_sub') . '/css/mmenu/jquery.mmenu.all.css');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'zen_sub') . '/js/mmenu/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js', 'file');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'zen_sub') . '/js/zensub.js', 'file');
```

I then add the menu to the zen theme in hook_preprocess_page through a preprocess variable:

```
$menu_left = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
$menu_left = menu_tree_output($menu_left);
$menu_left = drupal_render($menu_left);
$vars['mmenu_markup'] = array(
      '#markup' =>
        '<div id="menu-left">' . $menu_left . '</div>',
);
```

And finally I include placeholders for the menu, as well as the preprocess variable in my page.tpl.php

```
<div id="header-nav">
 <a href="#menu-left" class="menu-left"></a>
 <?php print variable_get('site_name', "ZenSub");?>
 <a href="#menu-right" class="menu-right"></a>
</div>

<?php print render($mmenu_markup); ?>
```

And Finally this is my js file (zensub.js) to set it all in motion:

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
    Drupal.behaviors.zensub = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            $('div#menu-left').once().mmenu({
               offCanvas: {
                   position: "left",
                   zposition: "front"
               },
               header   : true
            }, {
                // configuration object
               classNames: {selected: "active"}
            });

        }
    };

})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [Mobile Sliding Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/mmenu). It could save you a lot time and pain.

> The mobile sliding menu module integrates the mmenu jQuery plugin for
>   creating slick, app look-alike sliding menus for your mobile website.

Comment: And as much as I like this answer as it simplifies my development Mobile Sliding Menus suffers from exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Mobile Sliding Menu, the way I found to deal with stated problem is add custom module with:

```
function MYMODULE_mmenu_alter(&$mmenus) {

  // Disables left mmenu on some specific pages.
  if ( (arg(0) == 'admin' || arg(1) == 'add' || arg(1) == 'edit' || arg(2) == 'edit') && (arg(2) != 'mmenu') ) {
    $mmenus['mmenu_left']['enabled'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```